# special characters and &reg; is not working at the same time in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am using xslt 2.0 and generate xml 1.0.

when i used `disable-output-escaping="yes"` in xslt look like this:

```
<Desc><xsl:value-of select="$Desciption" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></Desc>
```

but sometimes `&reg` comes in between $Description variable value.so it create problem and i want to handle both situation `disable-output-escaping` and `&reg`.

I have used **Replace** and **translate** function but its **not worked**.

so I used this code to handle those situation.

```
 <xsl:if test="contains($Description, '&amp;reg;')">

        <xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($Description, '&amp;reg;')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($Description, '&amp;reg;')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="final" select="concat($before,'&#174;')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="finalDescription" select="concat($final,$after)"/>

     <Desc><xsl:value-of select="$finalDescription" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></Desc>

</xsl:if>
```

but when i used this disable-output-escaping="yes" it's not working. otherwise is working fine.

please give me suggestion how to handle both situation at the same time.

regards,
Jatin

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to use a named XML entity `&reg;` (usually ®) as if it is text. Then you are seem to say that you want to output `&reg;`, but that is not what your code does. You are (probably) outputting XML and disable-output-escaping only applies to things that actually need escaping which is then disabled. `&#x174;` does not require escaping, so it is not escaped.

The string functions like `fn:replace` do not have any influence on `disable-output-escaping`, they manipulate strings as they are known in memory, they do not manipulate the way they are serialized (which is what `disable-output-escaping` does).

You are using XSLT 2.0. You shouldn't use `disable-output-escaping` at all. It has been deprecated in XSLT 2.0 in favor of `xsl:character-map`, which is more flexible. Just put the character in there that you want escaped and when you need it escaped, use the character map (i.e. on `xsl:output` or `xsl-result-document`, you can even do that dynamically), and if you don't need it escaped, then don't use is.

I am not sure why you sometimes want it escaped and sometimes not. When you serialize XML, you will never see `&reg;`, you will see either the numerical reference or the actual character (depending on the selected encoding). If you want to see `&reg;` in one situation and `&amp;reg;` in another, the latter is simply a literal string, the former can be created, again, with character maps.

```
<xsl:character-map name="reg">
    <xsl:output-character char="&#174;" string="&amp;reg;" />
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:output use-character-maps="reg" />
```